# Cannot call value of non function type '[String:AnyObject]'

Tags: swift3

I'm facing the issue in Swift 3

I have following piece of code:

```
          do{
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as! [String : AnyObject]
            if let datasFromJson = json["blog"] as? [[String:AnyObject]] {
            for dataFromJson in datasFromJson{

                if let title = dataFromJson("title")! as? String {
                    article.author = author

                }
                self.articles?.append(article)
                }
            }
```

I get this error when I try to cast title as string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typo (brackets, not parentheses):

```
dataFromJson["title"] as? String // no exclamation mark after the closing bracket
```

Notes:

- `.mutableContainers` is useless in Swift.
- In Swift 3 JSON dictionary is `[String:Any]`
- Is `title` used at all? Or is it another typo `title` vs. `author`?

Comment: It works. It was typo.
Why .mutableContainer is useless?
Yup, title isn't typo.

Comment: You get mutability for free when assigning the object to a `var`iable regardless if `.mutableContainers` is specified or not.